# Why do I receive the error "This method must return a result of type ..."?

Tags: java

Can anyone see why I would receive the error "This method must return a result of type Card", when I clearly returns that variable "card" which is of type Card?

```
public Card playCard(int id){
    int i = 0;
    for (Card element : hand){
        if (i <= hand.size())
        {           
            if (element.getID() == id)
            {
                Card card = hand.get(i);
                hand.remove(i);
                return card;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("Card does not exist in     hand");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: You need to `return`from all of the possible execution flow.

Comment: Don't ever throw a `NullPointerException` yourself.

Comment: @arshajii Throwing `NullPointerException` explicitly after checking, instead of possibly doing some expensive processing and then accessing a `null`, is certainly fine. Explicit or implicit, exception should be the same (instead of `InvalidArgumentException` or whatever), caller should not need to care about implementatiln detail. Of course this has nothing to do with this question, just commenting on your "not ever".

Answer (score 5):

Your method doesn't return anything except in one possible scenario. It has to return something (or throw an exception) in *all* possible scenarios.

I *think* you meant to do this:

```
public Card playCard(int id){

    for (Card element : hand) {
        if (element.getID() == id) {
            return element;
        }
    }
    throw new SomeAppropriateException("Card does not exist in     hand");
}
```

...but I'm guessing a bit (as I don't know what `hand` is, but it looked a lot like a `List`). That code will always either execute the `return` statement or throw an exception, there's no way to get to the end of the method without one of those things happening.

Note that throwing a `NullPointerException` for a condition that isn't caused by a `null` pointer is a Bad Idea<sup>(tm)</sup>. (It's also best to be *consistent* in where you put your `{` and `}`.)

Comment: It should be noted that it can throw an error (like his/her NPE) in lieu of returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at by Tarlen, your code would need to be modified as such:

```
public Card playCard(int id){
    int i = 0;
    for (Card element : hand){
        if (i <= hand.size())
        {           
            if (element.getID() == id)
            {
                Card card = hand.get(i);
                hand.remove(i);
                return card;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("Card does not exist in     hand");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I believe that will account for all of the possible routes your program will need to take. You always gotta keep track of returning something EVERYWHERE the method can exit. If it can exit without hitting a return statement, you'll see that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is:

```
public Card playCard(int id){
```

which means you must return a `Card` object. Your code only has one return statement, but there are many paths through the code. You must return a `Card` object for each path

Answer (score 0):

It is because if `hand` is empty, then no value is being returned.

Add a `return` or a `throw` after your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a default `return` statement (or exception/error) for the whole method or at least one `return` statement (or exception/error) for every possible execution path in your code. As it is right now you have neither of them.